# Idiomatic way to destructively add elements to a list?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a nice way to add elements to a list stored in a variable? The ways I'm using aren't very pretty.

Starting list:

```
(setq sml/hidden-modes (list " hl-p"))
```

Add items to `sml/hidden-modes`:

```
;; First way I append the items to hidden-modes and set it again
(setq sml/hidden-modes (append sml/hidden-modes
                               (list " AC" " Undo-Tree" " Smrt")))

;; Second way I use add-to-list to add items one at a time instead of all at once
(mapcar (lambda (mode) (add-to-list 'sml/hidden-modes mode))
        (list " AC" " Undo-Tree" " Smrt"))

;; Way I see people doing it in random .emacs snippets I find
(add-to-list 'sml/hidden-modes " AC")
(add-to-list 'sml/hidden-modes " Undo-Tree")
(add-to-list 'sml/hidden-modes " Smrt")
```

Comment: Actually, `(setq sml/hidden-modes (append sml/hidden-modes (list ...)))` does not modify that variable destructively.  `append` copies each of its args except the last one.

Comment: Note that the `add-to-list` approach has the benefit of not modifying the list if the element already exists within it. This idempotency is nice in a `.emacs` because it means the config code can be re-evaluated without worry.

Answer (score 4):

If you know in advance that the original list is non-nil, you can try `nconc`:

```
ELISP> (setq a '(1 2 3))
(1 2 3)

ELISP> (nconc a '(4 5 6))
(1 2 3 4 5 6)

ELISP> a
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list library has [`!cons`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#cons-car-cdr) to prepend elements in-place:

```
(let ((xs '(2 3))) (!cons 1 xs) xs) ; (1 2 3)
```

Other than that read [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html)'s section [Modifying Existing List Structure](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Modifying-Lists.html#Modifying-Lists).